# Is it possible to generate link to JSON file that store in Google drive

Tags: json, google-drive-api, qlikview, qliksense

I have upload json file to my google drive, for using as source data for QlikSense (via REST API) with `permission = anyone`, with the link can view.

So is it possible to generate link from that file?

Thank you for your help

Regards

Answer (score 5):

Direct Download URL of regular file:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_ID

But I prefer another way, to copy the JSON data to a new Google Document (not regular file), then make it available to anyone with the link, and make your GET requests to a link like:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/YOUR_ID/export?format=txt

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!! Only the first URL format worked for me. Thank you so match!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get)

> Gets a file's metadata or content by ID.

Using the API Explorer, you can use this to see the actual API request and response

[image]

Then you will get a response:

[image]

If you will not be using the API you can get the link by right click -> Get shareable link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mr. Rebot,   

Thanks for your help.   It seem that it taking only file name and file type but i would like to get content inside the file.

Regards,

Comment: To get the file content, like in [v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) you should [download](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) the file to get the content.